# tsql to export and attach SSRS report to email?

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, t-sql, email, reporting-services

I don't think there's an easy way to do this, but here goes.

We have an `SSRS` report that can be invoked with `http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSales%2fSalesReport`

We also use database mail to send our emails, so the code looks like this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    
@profile_name = 'Joe Smith',    
@recipients = 'john@Company.com',    
@subject = 'Daily Sales',    
@body = 'Some HTML',    
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Using only tsql, can I somehow include the Excel as an attachment to the email sent?

The Excel can be viewed locally using `http://MyServer/ReportServer?%2fSaless%2fSalesReport&rs:Command=Excel`, but I'm not sure how I can include it as an attachment.

Thanks.

Comment: You can send file attachments using sp_send_mail using `@file_attachments='c:\myFile.xlsx'` but I don't think you can execute a report directly from T-SQL. You could look at subscriptions to solve this either directly to the recipient or schedule the report to dump the Excel file to a specific location and then you T-SQL sp_send_mail command would use that fixed network filename for the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using only TSQL, you'd remove the SSRS part of this problem. Instead of using the SSRS report, just call the code directly and use the results in `sp_send_dbmail` via the `@attach_query_result_as_file parameter`. If your SSRS report is formatting your results, and thus you **have** to use the SSRS report, then you can schedule this report to run and drop the xls on a file share which your SQL Server can access and send it with the `@file_attachments` parameter of `sp_send_db_mail`.

Comment: Glad to see somebody thinks the same way as me... but 30 seconds faster :)

Comment: From the looks of it, you were 30 seconds faster @AlanSchofield